# How to export a table row in mssql server to a file so that an import to a different location is possible

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sessions table which contains

```
sesssion_key (PK, bigint,not null),
created(datetime, not null)
content(image, null)
```

Now I need to import such a session to a file so that i can import it into another mssqsl instance.

Does someone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Are the instances on the same server? 
If so, just:`SELECT * into newDB.sessions FROM olddb.sessions;`

If they are not on the same server, go with either of Mithrandir's suggestions

Comment: I think he wants to do this an SQL Server, rather than MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the inport/export wizard from SSMS or the command line tool `bcp`. 
A bcp session might look like this:

Export data to a file:

```
 bcp databasae.schema.table out outputfile -S source_server -T -n
```

or

```
 bcp "SELECT sesssion_key, created, content FROM databasae.schema.table WHERE sesssion_key  = 0000001" queryout outputfile -S source_server -T -n
```

Then you can import the data to another server with the same table:

```
 bcp databasae.schema.table in inputfile -S destination_server -T -n
```

Comment: how can I restrict the output, so that only one row of my table will be exported? For example the one with the session 0000001

Comment: @AlPhaba: with bcp use `queryout` mode instead of `out` and give a query which restricts the resultset. using the wizard you can also give a query to restrict the result.

Comment: one step closer, but now my table cannot be found it says "invalid object name" I try it directly on sqlserver machine and with a user which has full access to this database. Here is my command: bcp "select * from form_instance_sessions fi where fi.instance_key = 2000000000196" queryout test.sql -S localhost -T -n
 -U db_user1

Comment: found it, I removed the -T option and defined the user then it worked. now i try to import